# How to access the terminal in Ubuntu GUI without a mouse

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, terminal

I have an embedded Ubuntu 12.04 system running with no monitor and I need to run a command in the terminal. I can connect a USB keyboard (or even a mouse, but a mouse would be difficult to use without a monitor) and log into the Ubuntu desktop. How can I bring up the terminal using only the keyboard without any visual feedback?

Comment: `ALT + F2`  and typing `gnome-terminal` ready.

Comment: Why are you operating in the dark like that? Can you not access this system via SSH?

Comment: @Jason If I could have, I would have. In fact connecting to wifi is exactly what I was going to do with the terminal.

Comment: @Matt been there before. Without any output though, I foresee a frustrating experience. Some alternatives to trying to configure your machine without any feedback: you could remove the hard drive and configure the wifi and ssh then replace it, or install an os on a flash drive with ssh and wifi set up then access the machine via this os with ssh and write the configurations to the internal hdd.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to another tty. That's probably easiest.

Comment: I sometimes have problems with tty1. `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` works each time.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work from the login screen as well?

Comment: @Matt Yes. You'll probably have to log in on the other tty as well though.

Comment: Yes I realize that (mostly because I just tried it out on another Ubuntu I'm on right now).

Comment: I think this does not prevent GUI opening in other TTYs. I meshed up my GPU settings so do not want to start it in GUI. Does this prevent GUI opening in other TTYs? The system seems to start GUI also in other TTY simultaneously.

Answer (score 24):

For **Unity** (shipped by default since the Ubuntu12), **Gnome**, **LXDE**, **Cinnamon** and **MATE**, the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut will work if you are already logged in.

If you are using **Xfce** (Xubuntu), however, it would be <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. (Note that Super is the Windows key)

And as far as I am aware, in **KDE**, while it is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, for some reason, there are issues with the default shortcuts. So you have a few other options. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `konsole` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you have full access to the system, and you want to set up a keyboard shortcut, right click on the Menu, find Konsole, select Advanced tab, Current shortcut key. Select a combination of your liking, though be careful with shortcuts already in use.

*As per Terdon's request, this answer has been expanded to provide information about the different Ubuntu environments.*

Comment: This is a great answer and will probably come in hand, but unfortunately in this situation Oliver's answer is better.

Comment: It is good when issues are resolved quickly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

[If you still have access to it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=851702), `ALT + F2` is essentially a one-time run dialog. It can be re-enabled in System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

This used to be a standard short cut. Why Canonical removed it, I'll never know.

http://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

Comment: I think it stopped working due to a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/1299784 - I just booted 20.04 from an ISO image and Alt+F2 worked just fine